# Hiding title in embed dailymotion videos?

Tags: dailymotion-api

I'm trying to hide the "title" in my embed dailymotion video which is connected on the https://
Does anybody has a code solution...

The code I have is:

By the way, Dailymotion had change the "rel=0" from (related videos) to "queue=0" which is 100% working

but now I'm struggling with the title... Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 2):

I think `ui-start-screen-info` is the parameter you are looking for.
Here is an example of how to use it with our Js SDK:

```js
let player = DM.player(document.getElementById("player"), {
  video: "x7xpiey",
  params: {
    'autoplay': false,
    'queue-enable': false,
    'ui-start-screen-info': false
  }
});
```

or directly using an embed code:

```html
<div style="position:relative;padding-bottom:56.25%;height:0;overflow:hidden;">
    <iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;overflow:hidden" frameborder="0" type="text/html" src="https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x7xpiey?queue-enable=false&ui-start-screen-info=false" width="100%" height="100%"   allow="autoplay" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

You can find all the others parameters available on the player in [the documentation](https://developer.dailymotion.com/player/#player-parameters)

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out, works fantastic! This is what I was searching for.